# How is price of 1 year Treasury Bills calculated on this chart?

Tags: government-bonds

The chart shows USD 0.85. I assume it is per USD 1000 face value T-Bill. What does this USD 0.85 mean?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

0.85% is the *yield*. you'll need to plug the yield, coupon rate, and time to maturity into a [bond price calculator](https://www.thecalculator.co/finance/Bond-Price-Calculator-606.html) to figure out what you actually pay to get that bond.

The higher the yield, the *less* you pay for bonds. Yield is a measure of the profit of the bond if it's held to maturity, so a lower price means a higher yield (profit).

As an example, if the bond matures in one year and pays a 1% coupon (0.5% semi-annually), then a yield of 0.85% means that the bond will cost 1,001.49

Comment: The chart has, indeed, two versions: yield value, as you described, and USD value, as shown on the chart. 0.85 is USD.

Comment: What is the source of the chart? It's _possible_ that it's the premium over par for the bond (e.g. you pay either 1000.85 or 1008.50 per bond) but I've never seen them quoted that way.

Comment: Here's the yield version of this chart. https://drive.google.com/file/d/190c7ohSzGyxjWZf1eXLSgvIiKX3wEPQs/view?usp=drivesdk

Comment: You can see the live chart here. https://www.tradingview.com/chart/3kkd5JSb/?symbol=TVC%3AUS01Y

Comment: Can you add the equivalent yield chart to the question? And I don't have access to the "live" chart.

Comment: I made my own chart in tradingview and there is no significant difference between the yield and "USD" chart. I suspect it's just an artifact of their platform - yield and price are inversely related so it cannot be purchase price or it would go down as yield goes up. It might be some measure of "income" meaning the amount the bond should pay in interest or go up in value but that would effectively be yield so it's not clear what the distinction is.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. The difference becomes significant if you select US10Y bonds. Yield value is 1.927 v USD 95'03'0 - whatever those apostrophes mean.

Comment: Yes but notice how US10 and US10Y move in opposite directions, which is what I would expect when comparing price and yield. I think the US10 is the price you pay per $100 of notional (e.g. $95.030). I suspect the US01 is just broken.